# Removing Empty Array Elements Originating From A .txt File Input

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I've been having problems trying to figure out a way to search through an array and just grab the lines of code from a .txt file that contains information. I want to be able to get rid of the empty return spaces(the empty array elements) that I would accidentally put into the Input file.

I have an array that reads all the lines from an input file. I've added a sample input that I added into the Sample Input File.

```
Line1 
Line2 
Line3

Line4
Line5
```

I have another array that will be the finalArray after all the spaces have been accounted for and should only be an array without the empty line returns. I can't seem to have it account for empty return elements.

I've just been getting the same output. I want it to read as;

```
Line1 
Line2 
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

It would make the second part of randomizing the array easier, If I can find a solution to account for empty array elements. I've added the code below for reference.

```
Imports System.IO

Module ListRandomizer
    Sub populateArray(ByVal inputArray() As String, ByRef startArray() As String)
        Dim pos As Integer = 0

        For Each element As String in inputArray
        If element <> "" Then
            startArray(pos) = element
        End If
        pos += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim myWriter As StreamWriter
        Dim inputArray() As String

        inputArray = File.ReadAllLines("sampleInput.txt")
        myWriter = New StreamWriter("sampleOutput.txt")

        Dim currLine As Integer = 1
        Dim size As Integer = 0

        For Each element As String in inputArray
        Console.WriteLine("LINE {0}, " & element, currLine)
                currLine += 1

        If element <> "" Then
            size += 1
        End If
        Next    

        Console.Writeline(size)
        Dim startArray(size) As String

        populateArray(inputArray, startArray)

        For Each fern As String in startArray
        Console.WriteLine("LINE {0}, " & fern, currLine)
                currLine += 1
        Next

        myWriter.Close()
        System.Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
inputArray = File.ReadAllLines("sampleInput.txt").Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadlAllText() then Split() with StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries:

```
inputArray = File.ReadAllText("sampleInput.txt").Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```